# Jquery.ui : Get id from current element

Tags: jquery, resize, resizable

How do I get the id of current element while I'm resizing? the following I made does not work, thank you

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(document).ready(
function(){
    $( ".resizable" ).resizable({
        resize: function( event, ui ) {alert(ui.element.id)}
    })
}
);
</script>

<img class="resizable" id="25" src="test1.jpg">
<img class="resizable" id="26" src="test2.jpg">
<img class="resizable" id="27" src="test3.jpg">
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this was mentioned, but in HTML ID cannot start with a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$( ".resizable" ).resizable({
    resize: function( event, ui ) {
            alert($(ui.element).children('img').attr('id'));
    }
});
```

Comment: @HermannGolden after some testing i discovered it adds a wrapper div so you need to use $(ui.element).children('img').attr('id'). I've updated my answer to show this

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this)`. It worked for me.